Enable Extensions from the command line
A separate extension can be enabled via the gnome-extensions enable command. How to enable common Extensions from the command line?


What is the version of Ubuntu you are using?

ubuntu 22.04, gnome 42.9 @David

Please edit the question and add this info not as a comment.

Following command will enable all extensions:
gsettings set org.gnome.shell disable-user-extensions false


@Ajay thank you for the correction!
